# Creating Page object programmatically got error ValidationError path and depth fields cannot be blank/null

Tags: django, wagtail

I am trying to programmatically create a `PostPage` object. This class inherits from wagtail's [`Page`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/pages.html) model:

```
post = PostPage.objects.create(
    title='Dummy',
    intro='This is just for testing dummy',
    body='Lorem ipsum dolor...',
    first_published_at=datetime.strptime(f'2019-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> `ValidationError: {'path': ['This field cannot be blank.'], 'depth': ['This field cannot be null.']}`

I need to create some dummy `Page` objects, so I wonder how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found some information that helped me solve this problem at Google Groups' wagtail support [question 1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/wagtail/Get0wrrJ-3c/Me-s_g93AQAJ)  and [question 2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wagtail/21zDuOyi9aw). Basically, I cannot create directly the `Page` object, but I have to add it to another existing page as follows:

```
# assuming HomePage has at least one element
home = HomePage.objects.all()[0]

post = PostPage(
        title='Dummy',
        intro='This is just for testing dummy',
        body='Lorem ipsum dolor...',
        first_published_at=datetime.strptime(f'2019-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'),
)
home.add_child(instance=post)
home.save()
```

This worked like a charm!

Comment: How would you go around creating the Home/Root Page then?